# Disabling cache for a certain block used in the product page

Tags: frontend, cache, product-page, magento2.4.2

I would like to load a certain message based on a certain hour range on the product page.
In the `catalog_product_view.xml` I have this block:

```
<block class="Vendor\Products\Block\Usp" name="product_view_page" template="Vendor_Products::usp.phtml" before="product.info.overview"/>
```

By adding the `cacheable="false"` it works, based on certain hours I will get the right message. But I'm not sure if it 'safe' to use, especially on the product page. Reading some posts, everyone tries to avoid it!

By adding this method:

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return false;
}
```

or `$this->_isScopePrivate = true;` to my `Usp` block class, will not work!
Would you please explain me if it safe to use? or maybe suggest some alternatives ?

Side note: I am running Magento 2.4.2-p1.

Thank you

Comment: i think, you should try to use the data-bind html for make them dynamic without caching.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid setting the "cachable false" because then all your product page wont be cached since Magento first checks all the cachable blocks in the layout and if at least one of them have cachable false it wont cache anything of the page.

To dynamically change something inside a cached layout you'll have to use either ko.js or ajax calls (So you'll have to build a custom API)

Comment: do you have link or post, something similar that I could use as an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding cacheable=false will tell Magento not to cache the entire page. You can check this link and do similar kind of changes as per your needs.

https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-render-an-html-using-an-ajax-call-in-magento-2-module/